# Compiling with Cuda in Qt gives linking error

Tags: c++, qt4, cuda

I am trying to compile Cuda code (in the form of .cu files) in Qt Creator 4.8.0 on a 32-bit Windows 7 system, and I am currently failing.

I put together the following project file:

```
TARGET = TestCUDA
DESTDIR = release
OBJECTS_DIR = release/obj
CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR = release/cuda

SOURCES += main.cpp
CUDA_SOURCES += test.cu

CUDA_SDK = "C:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2/C" # Path to cuda SDK install
CUDA_DIR = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v4.2" # Path to cuda toolkit install

INCLUDEPATH += $$CUDA_DIR/include \
               $$CUDA_SDK/common/inc/ \
               $$CUDA_SDK/../shared/inc/
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib/Win32 \
                $$CUDA_SDK/common/lib/Win32 \    
                $$CUDA_SDK/../shared/lib/Win32
LIBS += -lcuda -lcudart
CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,'" -I"','-I"','"')   # this is to put quotes around paths with spaces

cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
cuda.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.ptx
cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS --machine 32 -ptx -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
```

This is supposed to produce a test_cuda.ptx module in the release/cuda/ folder. Incidentally, that's exactly what it does, hurrah! 
BUT it also gives a LNK1107 error:

```
C:\path\to\release\cuda\test_cuda.ptx:-1: error: LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0xFCC
```

I do not know why this happens, nor how to solve it. The location indicated in this error is somewhere in the middle of the `test_cuda.ptx` file, but that's not of any help. What's also strange is that this same file works perfectly when I import it in another Cuda application, so the file is not corrupt. The `main.cpp` is completely empty:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {}
```

so that's not where the linker could go wrong. It seems like the linker is linking stuff it shouldn't link, but I don't know why, or how to stop this. Anyone an idea?

Comment: I am not an expert with qmake but it seems that you are trying to link your object files directly with 'ptx' which an intermediate format. You can try to replace '-ptx -o ${...}' by '-cubin -o ${...}' in your nvcc command line And also change cuda.output to blabla.cubin. Also as my person impression, have you tried using cmake instead ? this is a lot more easier, ie. no need to write all nvcc commands by hand..

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, but it does not work: this way, I get the same linking error at some random place in the .cubin file. But using `-c` instead (see @harrism's answer) and changing `${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.ptx` to `${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o` did work.

Comment: actually I was mistaken, @harrism is right, you need to compile with -c option instead while -cubin just applies ptxas on ptx files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @asm you are compiling to PTX intermediate files and then trying to link them as object files. But counter to @asm's suggestion, you should not compile to cubin, but to object files.  To do so, you want the `-c` option rather than the `-ptx` option:

```
cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
cuda.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS --machine 32 -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
```

Caveat: not a QMAKE user so the above might not be exactly right. I second the recommendation for CMake.

Comment: I also want to build a pure CUDA application using Qt Creator / cmake. Both - CUDA and cmake - is new for me. Is there some example cmake file that you could provide as a template?